# Get date in YYYYMM format of a year ago

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get the date in `YYYYMM` format such that each month it generates the result of 12 months (1 year) ago.

I have tried this, however it will always result in `201907` in any month.

```sql
SELECT convert(varchar(6),DATEFROMPARTS ( DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) - 1, 7, 1 ),112)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()), 112)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. How about if I now want to get the previous months date in the same format? e.g. I want to get 202007. This gives me 202007 Select convert(varchar(6),DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 7, 1),112) however, I want to get the previous month each month and not always get 202007.

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp)