# Get last day of a year ago in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

How do I get the last day of a year ago? e.g. `2019-08-31` such that each month it generates the last day of a year ago.

I tried this:

```
select convert(varchar(10),dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0)),120)
```

Comment: Isn't this just a repetition of your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63502822/2029983) with slightly different logic?

Comment: Is it really so difficult to use "month" instead of "mm" as the datepart parameter in your datediff function? And perhaps some white space to make your code so much more readable and understandable?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you can use `DATEADD` to work out the date 1 year ago, and then you can use the `EOMONTH` function to get the last day of that month. Easier than trying to mess about with `DATEDIFF`.

So this will work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EOMONTH(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())), 120)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ade8d8251e653a8791ae3f5d51120f46

Documentations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just use `DATEFROMPARTS`, as you can hard code the month and day values (it's not like the last month and day of a year is changing from 31 December):

```sql
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,12,31);
```